# Filter Data Using a ComboBox Vb.net ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I'm developing an app to generate reports based on the data from database and I'm facing a difficulty trying to filter the data using a ComboBox, when I filter data for the first time it shows the data related to the value of the ComboBox then when I try to filter again it shows the data of the previous ComboBox value and the current ComboBox value.

First value:
[image: Data filtered for the first time]

Second value:
[image: After changing the value to another]

My code:

```
Sub GetReport()
        Dim rpt As New ReportDataSource
        Try
            With ReportViewer1.LocalReport
                .DataSources.Clear()
            End With
            conn.openOcean()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM loins WHERE projectcode= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ORDER BY code ASC", conn.getConnection)
        adapter.Fill(ds.Tables("dtLoins"))
        rpt = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("dtLoins"))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpt)
        ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Each time this code is run you are adding another datasource. You need to clear the previous one before adding a new one.

Comment: I tried to do that adding this line 'ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()' but still not working...

Comment: Similarly you are calling .Fill repeatedly on the same table.

Comment: @peterG Still can't solve the problem man...

Comment: Can you confirm the ClearBeforeFill property on the TableAdapter is set to True? What happens if you set a breakpoint and hover your mouse over the dataset ds? You should be able to drill into the contents of the table and confirm it's empty before calling 'Fill'

Comment: @peterG I didn't use TableAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you have done to fix this but could you possibly clear your dataset? Since it is declared outside of this sub, you could potentially be appending your data to the existing data each time .Fill is called.

Could you place a breakpoint on the

```
adapter.Fill(ds.Tables("dtLoins"))
```

line and use the watch window to query the row count of the dataset?

If it isn't zero before fill, it's keeping the previous rows.

You could call

```
ds.Clear()
```

before the fill to see if that helps.

This is just my two cents from what information I have to go off of.

Comment: Never worked with ReportViewer but maybe this ?   .DataSources.Clear() then ReportViewer1.Clear()